# ElasticSearch 6.6.0 Aggregation Avg with script not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following I am trying to run on my cluster:

```
GET _search
{
  "aggs": {
    "buckets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "main_feature_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_dwell": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "dwell.dwell_ms",
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "long x = Math.round(_value*100)/100000; return x;"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But no matter what I try I cannot get it to round the result.

Here is what the result looks like:

```
"doc_count" : 26032,
      "average_dwell" : {
        "value" : 44.87277178006528
      }
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong I am sure it is something obvious.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the value you get without script and what is the expected value?

Comment: @NishantSaini hello, a segment from the actual result is shown above, I was expecting value to be 44.87

Comment: If you change the script to `"return _value"`, what do you get?

Comment: @NishantSaini “value” : 448772.77178006528, I just want to round the it to lesser precision.

Comment: Ok I want little more clarity now, you want to round it to 44.87 or 448772.77 ?

Comment: @NishantSaini I want it rounded to the two digits of precision so 44.87.

Comment: Might be a silly ques but what if the value is 578.473747488? You still want it to be 57.84?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_value` script applies the script on each value of the document and then calculates the average of the modified values. What you seem to achieve is to reduce the precision to two decimal places. This can be achieved by making use of [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) to get the expected value.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "buckets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "main_feature_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_dwell": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "dwell.dwell_ms"
          }
        },
        "rounded_avg": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "curr_avg": "average_dwell"
            },
            "script": "Math.round(params.curr_avg * 100)/100.0;"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```